# Unravel UI data not populating

Tags: core-services

**DB auth issue**

In sensor log error:

"unable to decrypt the password" and DB connect is failing"

with ./manager we can decrypt the password but starting the service it failing with decrypt.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

update the unravel properties file with decrypted password and restarted the service.

restart unravel service